# Can't use Timber but have implemented the dependency

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I am trying to use Timber for logging and I did implement the dependency for it but when I use the keyword Timber, it appears red and have no option in the menu to fix it here are the images:

[image: implementation of timber]

[image: making use of timber]

Comment: are your auto imports are on in the android studio or did you try to rebuild with proper internet connection?

Comment: I tried rebuilding and syncing but it does not change

Comment: `import timber.log.Timber` or alt+Enter -> import

Comment: I solved it, I didn't sync project with gradle files and used sync app instead

Comment: putting the answer, accept it so, this question seemed to answer to others.

Answer (score 0):

Few ways you can solve this:

1. Check if your auto-import is on
2. Import using import pop-up when you hover on the error
3. Try rebuilding the project
4. Sync the project when you add dependency or sync twice, might get internet connection errors